# Show/hide divs based on select value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want a dropdown select menu to show textboxes based on the value:

```
var showDiv = function(goal){  
    var count = 1;  
    $('.myDIV').each(function(){  
    if(count <= goal){  
    $(this).show().nextAll('.group').hide()  
    }  

        count = count +1  
    });  
};  

var goal = $('#mySelect').val();  
showDiv(goal)  

$('#mySelect').change(function(){  

       showDiv($(this).val())   
});
```

I'm trying but it's not working, here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/jdveR/

What i want is;

If select 1; show 1 div
If select 2; show 1 and 2 div
If select 3; show 1, 2 and 3 div goes like that.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please show the (relevant) code here, and provide an actual link, don't just post the text of the link in order to get around the prompt asking you to add code.

Comment: Amazing how creative people can get to avoid including code with a link to jsfiddle!

Comment: For what it's worth, the problem with your code is that you're not first hiding all elements. `$('.myDIV').hide().each(...` would solve your problem. Having said that, you don't need to manually iterate over the set here; Sushanth's solution is preferable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:lt()` selector. You need not iterate over the elements in the first place.

This will select the `divs` based on the index of the div.

```
var showDiv = function (goal) {
    $('.myDIV').hide();
    $('.myDIV:lt(' + goal + ')').show();
};

$('#mySelect').change(function () {
    showDiv($(this).val())
}).change();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdveR/7/)**

Comment: I was going to suggest using filter() but this is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jdveR/10/

```
var showDiv = function(goal){
    $('.myDIV').hide();
    var count = 1;  
    $('.myDIV').each(function(){  
        if(count <= goal){  
            $(this).show().nextAll('.group').hide()  
        }
       count = count +1; 
});  
};  

var goal = $('#mySelect').val();  
showDiv(goal);

$('#mySelect').on('change', function(){ 
       showDiv($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your data separate from the design then you could try adding `data-goal="x"` to your divs and changing your javascript to this:

HTML:

```
<div class="myDIV" id="div1" data-goal="1">Div1</div>  
<div class="myDIV" id="div2" data-goal="2">Div2</div>  
<div class="myDIV" id="div3" data-goal="3">Div3</div>  
<div class="myDIV" id="div4" data-goal="4">Div4</div>  
<div class="myDIV" id="div5" data-goal="5">Div5</div>
```

Javascript

```
var showDiv = function(goal){  
    $('.myDIV').hide().each(function(){
      if( $(this).attr('data-goal') <= goal )
         $(this).show();
    });
};  

var goal = $('#mySelect').val();  
showDiv(goal)  

$('#mySelect').change(function(){  
       showDiv($(this).val())   
});
```